# Play/Pause any Canvas animation

Tags: javascript, animation, iframe, canvas

I'm building a tool where I have an IFRAME inside of which a user can put any HTML containing a canvas animation.

The purpose is to let them choose if they want to use createJS, Adobe Edge Animate or any other tool they prefer.

Despite this I need to be able to play and pause this canvas animation no matter which tool they used.

Do you think this is possible? Or do you think I will be tied to the framework they used?

I've tried clearing the request animation frame of the page but it didn't work well.

```
iframe.contentWindow.cancelAnimationFrame(<don't know what to put in here without accessing the animation framework>)
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you!

Andrea

**EDIT:**
In my case scenario the iframe is a sort of sand-box where the user can put whatever it wants, even the javascript for the functioning of the framework he used

Comment: *I've tried clearing the request animation frame of the page but it didn't work well* - does this mean it worked in some capacity or did it not work at all? The immediate thing that comes to mind in scenarios like this is to provide an *interface* (as best as javascript will allow) for the developers of the external content to use so that whatever content loads provides those APIs such your container can elicit a proper response.

Comment: do you want to be able to pick up the animation where it left off after pausing it?

Comment: @jusopi sorry, it didn't work at all.

Comment: @user2072826 yes it would be nice to be able to pick up the animation

Answer (score 1):

**Supporting different Html5 Canvas libraries**

It is theoretically possible because while most libraries have their own built-in animation methods, you can certainly just use their drawing methods and then use your own animation loop to animate their drawings.

But, Wow! This would be a huge task. Just off the top of my head you would have to:

1. Load only the code of the users selected library - eg. `Easel.js`.
2. Create a canvas DOM element which any library must use to display drawings.
3. Create a hook to let them set up their particular libraries environment. For example, this is where the EaselJS user would create their stage: `var stage = new createjs.Stage("theRequiredCanvas");`
4. Create a hook to let them run their brand of code inside your animation loop.
5. To hook their code into your framework, you would have to require them to put all their code into a `.js` file that is loaded with your framework.

*Stopping...!*

I'm going to stop reasoning out a solution here because this would be more work for the user than just using their own library.

**The easy part of your question: Pausing & Continuing an animation**

You can set a flag that stops the animation loop.

When you want to continue the animation you clear that flag and request the animation loop.

Example code:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


// animation will pause when paused==true
var paused=false;

// testing, a rotation angle for the animated rect
var angle=0;

// pause the animation on #pause click
$('#pause').on('click',function(){
  paused=true;
});

// continue the animation on #continue click
$('#continue').on('click',function(){
  paused=false;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
});

// start the animation loop
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
  if(paused){return;}

  // animate anything
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.translate(cw/2,ch/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.fillRect(-50,-50,100,100);
  ctx.strokeRect(-50,-50,100,100);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  // increase the angle for the next loop
  angle+=Math.PI/60;

  // request another animation loop
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='pause'>Pause</button>
<button id='continue'>Continue</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your snippet markE, but doesn't it mean that I should override any "animate" method of any framework out there to insert that "pause" variable?

Comment: You would want to use your own framework's animation method (overriding every libraries animation method would be a monumental task). Your animation method would simply draw/animate any library's shapes on the canvas. ;-)